# Diferença entre JQuery.Append() e JQuery.Html()

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hoje fazendo a manipulação de conteúdo de um modal me veio duas possibilidades à mente

```js
$('div').append('Olá mundo!');
```

Ou então:

```js
$('div').html('Olá mundo!');
```

Porém não sei exatamente qual seria o ideal mesmo sabendo que as duas me atenderia.

Minha dúvida é em qual contexto devo utilizar uma ou outra? Qual a diferença?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando a função `append` você adiciona o código HTML como o último filho do elemento pai. Vamos tomar o seguinte exemplo:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Ao executar a instrução: `$('div').append('Olá mundo!');` o resultado é o seguinte:

```
<div>
    <p>Hello World</p>
    "Olá Mundo!"
</div>
```

---

Usando a função `html` você sobreescreve todo o HTML contido no elemento pai.

```
<div>
    <p>Hello World</p>
</div>
```

Após utilizar a função `$('div').html('Olá mundo!');` o resultado esperado é o seguinte:

```
<div>
    "Olá mundo!"
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`.append()` irá incluir o conteudo(ou objeto DOM) ao final do elemento do contexto em questão, enquanto que `.html()` irá sobreescrever todo o conteudo dentro do elemento do contexto em questão com o novo valor passado como parâmetro do método. Logo para quando utilizar um ou outro, deve-se pensar qual o resultado desejado: se deseja apenas incluir um novo conteudo à um elemento qualquer deve-se utilizar `.append()`, já quando se deseja substituir deve-se utilizar `.html()`

Comment: Acho que com jquery o DOM é sempre sobrescrito, a diferença é que com o `append()` ele sobrecreve mantendo o anterior e adicionando um novo, e com o o `html()` ele sobrescreve, excluindo o anterior

Comment: sim, é isso que minhas palavras quiseram dizer. `append()` incluí e `html()` substituí

Comment: pq no caso o DOM é sempre reescrito, a menos que esteja usando um framework como o react que utiliza o VDOM que evita o recarregamento completo do dom e só sobrescreve objeto que deve ser sobrescrito, melhorando o desempenho da página.

Answer (score 0):

O `$.html()` tem duas funções:

**1)** Retornar o HTML interno de um elemento:

```
<div>
   <p>Parágrafo</p>         <---
   <a href="url">Link</a>       | HTML interno
   <br>                     <---  
</div>
```

Ao fazer `$("div").html()` irá retornar o código HTML dentro da div.

**2)** Adicionar HTML a um elemento, substituindo o que houver:

Ao fazer `$("div").html("Olá mundo!")` irá substituir o HTML interno da div, resultando em:

```
<div>
   Olá mundo!
</div>
```

O `$.append()` apenas adiciona HTML no final do elemento (não substitui o que houver).

Ao fazer `$("div").append("Olá mundo!")`, o resultado será:

```
<div>
   <p>Parágrafo</p>
   <a href="url">Link</a>
   <br>
   Olá mundo!
</div>
```

Quando usar um ou outro vai depender do que você quer fazer. Se quiser apenas adicionar HTML a um elemento mantendo o que já existir, use o `.append()`. Se quer substituir o HTML do elemento por outro, use `.html()`.